# Creating a graph from a math function

Tags: python, function, math, matplotlib, graph

I am having trouble learning to plot a function in python. For example I want to create a graph with these two functions:

```
y=10x
y=5x+20
```

The only way I found was to use the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([points go here], [points go here])
plt.plot([points go here], [points go here])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

and to manually enter data points, but I have some tougher problems coming up so that would be really difficult.

Is there a way to just put in what function I need a plot for and have python create the graph for me?

Answer (score 1):

this is rough, but it will work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random 

x = [1, 2, 4,6, 7, 100, 200, 100, 34]
tenxArray = []
fiveXPlusTwenty = []

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    tenxArray.append(10*x[i])
    fiveXPlusTwenty.append(5*x[i] + 20)

plt.plot(x, tenxArray)
plt.plot(x, fiveXPlusTwenty)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) generator to generate x values and list comprehensions to calculate y values for your functions:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun1(x):
    return 10*x

def fun2(x):
    return 5*x+20

MAX_X = # A maximum value for x goes here
x = range(MAX_X)

y1,y2 = zip(*[ (fun1(val), fun2(val)) for val in x ])

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```